# How to track whether a function can throw in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, exception, types

The [announcement for `js-sys`](https://rustwasm.github.io/2018/09/26/announcing-web-sys.html#the-js-sys-crate-is-100-feature-complete) said:

> We considered a TypeScript frontend, but did not prioritize it because TypeScript does not describe whether or not functions throw exceptions

1) Is this correct?
2) If not, what are the ways to mark whether functions can throw in TS? Are there ways the compiler can help?

Here are two solutions. The first does not actually check the types, but they are at least visible as a way to communicate with other programmers. The second way does some limited checking, but has a minor run-time cost and requires manual effort.

```
// unchecked solution
type OrThrow<T> = T;

function add(a: number, b: number): OrThrow<number> {
    return a + b;
}

// checked solution with run-time cost and manual work
type Exn<T> = T & { __canThrow: true };

function exn<T>(t: T): Exn<T> {
    return t as Exn<T>;
}

function sum(a: number, b: number): Exn<number> {
    return exn(a + b);
}
```

Comment: I believe this has to do with TypeScript's relationship to JavaScript... essentially any code can raise an exception even if its typings are correct. For example trying to access a property path on an undefined property or variable (`data.data.data`). That is to say _any_ function can raise a runtime exception. However, there is no way to specify the type of error that may get thrown.

Comment: You want [this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219), I think.  Go over there and  or comment if you think you have a convincing use case that hasn't been discussed.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, understood, this is more about communicating via the types that a function is intended to throw in some cases. I provided two examples of how to do that, but don't like either.

Comment: This question isn't directly related to checked exceptions, but interesting discussion of checked exceptions [here](https://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to describe it.
One option to track it might be using `Result`/`Either` type, used in more strongly typed languages like Rust, Scala, OCaml and Haskell.
You might also be interested in runtime cost of what you use (newtype pattern). [Example](https://github.com/gcanti/newtype-ts#performance) actually uses deeper nesting and more overhead, while cost is basically nothing.

Comment: Result/Either/Maybe could be represented just fine in TS, but that's not what I was asking about. The second solution I proposed seems to meet the criteria of "describing whether or not functions throw" but I was checking my understanding and asking if there's a better way.